# Grunt and Bower Dependency Management

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, frontend, bower

I am new to whole front-end tooling and I am trying to start a new jquery plugin project. So, with Grunt I used [grunt-init-jquery](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-jquery) to make me a boilerplate jquery plugin project and it already has unminified versions of client framework dependecies as well such as jquery and qunit.

It also generates `package.json` which I can edit to contain `dependencies` so, how does Bower fit here? or is optional and I can handle both server and client side dependencies with Grunt only?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing *Grunt* with *Npm*, because the *Grunt* cannot handle dependencies, it's "simply" a task runner. The `package.json` file is here because you need the `devDependencies` for the *Grunt* installation and all its plugins (like [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)). This file is associated with *Npm* and not specifically *Grunt*.

*Bower* is solely for front-end dependencies. Even if you can handle them with *Npm*, it's better to use *Bower* since it's optimized for this purpose (no deep dependencies among other things).

So manage the things you need for the **development of your plugin with Npm**, and **Bower for your plugin dependencies** (since a *jQuery plugin* is usually for the front-end).